# Concurrency checking for Swift 6

Tags: swift, concurrency

In Swift versions starting from 5.7, developers have the flexibility to select among three levels of concurrency checking: Minimal, Targeted, or Complete. This allows for a gradual approach to handling concurrency. Looking ahead to Swift 6, will the concurrency checking options remain the same, or is there a possibility that the default mode will shift to 'Complete'? And hence this change leading to the transformation of current warnings into errors during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WWDC 2022 video [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/?time=1615), they say

> “Complete” checking approximates the intended Swift 6 semantics to completely eliminate data races.

So, not only will “complete” be the default in Swift 6 (or something that closely approximates it), but there is a good chance that it may be the only option at that point in time.

So, this is the time to experiment with the “targeted” and “complete” options, and start to address the issues now, well before Swift 6 is released.

Personally, when I first tried these options in legacy projects, I was presented with a daunting list of issues. But, assuming you are already writing (largely) thread-safe code (code that passes TSAN diagnostics, as discussed in [Diagnosing memory, thread, and crash issues early](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/)), it largely becomes an issue of learning some of the new conventions to make sure the compiler can reasonably verify the thread-safety. And, in my case, at least, it actually helped me uncover a few issues.

It really is not as bad as it looks at first blush.